# Which Stripe subscriptions have expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to write a ruby rails rake task that lists all the stripe customers whose subscriptions have expired? I have looked at the stripe api but do can't see how I can retrieve this information.

Kind Regards

Gurdipe

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this in stripe unless you loop through each customer and check the status for each subscription that this customer might have. In your case a customer has one subscription or more?

Comment: Thank you for the quick update, the customers we have I think only have one subscription each.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I could think of is to get the customer subscription statuses from stripe for each customer:

```
2.1.1 :082 > a =Stripe::Customer.all.collect{|c| c.subscriptions.collect{|s| [c.id, s.status]}}.reject(&:empty?)
 => [[["cus_5VT4xC8uCoVIV5", "trialing"]], [["cus_5VT4Oh4AX74vqN", "trialing"]], [["cus_5VT4GFL6pPvsmH", "trialing"]], [["cus_5VT4uePgqT4Rrz", "trialing"]], [["cus_5VT4F8c8iK9cG8", "trialing"]], [["cus_5VT4zO0iMjoKsu", "trialing"]], [["cus_5VT4XQkAKCmRmg", "trialing"]]] 
2.1.1 :083 >
```

In my case they are all demo customers so they all have trial status, next you should loop through this to save customers which subscription status is equal to `active` or `trial` and save into a variable, then using customer id from stripe you can find users in your app.

p.s. In case you need it as json (ugly, but... what can you do):

```
2.1.1 :111 > b = a.map{|r| "#{r[0][0]}, #{r[0][1]}"}.join(', ').split(', ')
 => ["cus_5VT4xC8uCoVIV5", "trialing", "cus_5VT4Oh4AX74vqN", "trialing", "cus_5VT4GFL6pPvsmH", "trialing", "cus_5VT4uePgqT4Rrz", "trialing", "cus_5VT4F8c8iK9cG8", "trialing", "cus_5VT4zO0iMjoKsu", "trialing", "cus_5VT4XQkAKCmRmg", "trialing"] 
2.1.1 :112 > h = Hash[*b]
 => {"cus_5VT4xC8uCoVIV5"=>"trialing", "cus_5VT4Oh4AX74vqN"=>"trialing", "cus_5VT4GFL6pPvsmH"=>"trialing", "cus_5VT4uePgqT4Rrz"=>"trialing", "cus_5VT4F8c8iK9cG8"=>"trialing", "cus_5VT4zO0iMjoKsu"=>"trialing", "cus_5VT4XQkAKCmRmg"=>"trialing"} 
2.1.1 :113 >
```

**update**

https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination use `starting_after` and `ending_before` params to navigate trough stripe customers records.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome update. I thought all I would need to do is find the customers with a status of "unpaid" and that the status of "unpaid" is set by stripe automatically when a payment fails is this correct?  Also I have more than a 100 customers how do I use the Stripe::Customer.all to get more than a 100 customers?

Comment: Actually to iterate thru all the customers I find this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544897/is-it-possible-to-get-a-count-of-subscribers-for-a-plan-from-the-stripe-api

Comment: See the update in the answer. Also there is no such thing as `paid` or `unaid` for customer, these attributes are for invoices, and after all attempts to get it paid the subscription becomes `inactive.`

Comment: Again thanks for the awesome update, I am struggling to update the above commands to page thru using ther parameters Stripe::Customer.all(limit: limit, starting_after: last_customer), how can i find the last_customer id when using the collect

Comment: When you load first 100 customers you will save them into a variable for example `customer_list`, so from this list you need to save the last one into `last_customer` variable with `customer_list.last` and use it for your next request.